# yii subdomain doesn't recognize the module

Tags: php, yii, routes, subdomain

I am trying to build subdomain for my module in Yii but I am experiencing an error. Here is the routes:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'showScriptName'=>false,
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                'http://<module:\w+>.mydomain.net/'=>'<module>/default/index',
                'http://<module:\w+>.mydomain.net/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<module>/<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
```

The error I am getting is really weird. The domain: `http://cp.mydomain.net/cp/auth/login` takes me to /cp/auth/login (module/controller/action). however, `http://cp.domain.net/auth/login` says

`Unable to resolve the request "auth/login".`

Comment: can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Check the file permission of your Controller. Sometimes it create some problem.

Comment: file permissions are all www-data:www-daat